# Multiclass classification in SVM

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I have been working on "Script identification from bilingual documents".
I want to classify the pages/blocks as either Eng(class 1), Hindi (class 2) or Mixed using libsvm in matlab. but the problem is that the training data i have consists of samples corresponding to Hindi and english pages/blocks only but no mixed pages.

The test data i want to give may consists of Mixed pages/blocks also, in that case i want it to be classified as "Mixed". I am planning to do it using confidence score or probability values. like if the prob value of class 1 is greater than a threshold (say 0.8) and prob value of class 2 is less than a threshold say(0.05) then it will be classified as class 1, and class 2 vice-versa. but if aforementioned two conditions dont satisfy then i want to classify it as "Mixed".

The third return value from the "libsvmpredict" is prob_values and i was planning to go ahead with this prob_values to decide whether the testdata is Hindi, English or Mixed. but at few places i learnt that "libsvmpredict" does not produce the actual prob_values.

Is there any way which can help me to classify the test data into 3 classes( Hindi, English, Mixed) using training data consisting of only 2 classes in SVM.

Comment: Is the Hindi text written in Latin characters? If not, I don't think you need a classifier since the computer clearly already recognizes and displays English/Hindi characters correctly. That is, you can identify that language by looking at the (likely UTF-8) encoded characters.

Comment: The documents i have are scanned images from hindi/english books at 300dpi. The whole purpose of my project is to identify the script of the input document image and on the basis of identified script it will be passed to appropriate OCR, which in turn convert the image to computer readable format.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the modus operandi for SVMs.
In no way SVMs can predict a given class without knowing it, without knowing how to separate such class from all other classes.

The function `svmpredict()` in LibSVM actually shows the probability estimates and the greater this value is, the more confident you can be regarding your prediction. But you cannot rely on such values if you have just two classes in order to predict a third class: indeed `svmpredict()` will return as many decision values as there are classes.

You can go on with your thresholding system (which, again, is not SVM-based) but it most likely fail or give bad performances. Think about that: you have to set up two thresholds and use them in a logic AND manner. The chance of correctly classified non-Mixed documents will indeed drastically decrease.

My suggestion is: instead of wasting time setting up thresholds, with a high chance of bad performances, join some of these texts together or create some new files with some Hindi and some English lines in order to add to your training data some proper Mixed documents and perform a standard 3-classes SVM system.
In order to create such files you can as well use Matlab, which has a pretty decent file I/O functions such as `fread()`, `fwrite()`, `fprintf()`, `fscanf()`, `importdata()` and so on...